# Passing ng-template to child component

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template

I have created a reusable component that will render a table. It is currently working for basic tables, but there are scenarios where I would like to be able to customize an individual column/cell within the table.

Here's the code I'm using in the parent component:

```
<!-- PARENT TEMPLATE -->
<app-table
  [headers]="headers"
  [keys]="keys"
  [rows]="rows">
</app-table>

// PARENT COMPONENT
public headers: string[] = ['First', 'Last', 'Score', 'Date'];
public keys: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'quizScore', 'quizDate'];
public rows: Quiz[] = [
  { 'John', 'Doe', 0.75, '2020-01-03T18:18:34.549Z' },
  { 'Jane', 'Doe', 0.85, '2020-01-03T18:19:14.893Z' }
];
```

And the code I'm using in the child component:

```
<!-- CHILD TEMPLATE -->
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let header of headers">
        {{ header }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
      <td *ngFor="let key of keys">
        {{ render(key, row) }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

// CHILD COMPONENT
@Input() headers: string[];
@Input() keys: string[];
@Input() rows: any[];

render(key: string, row: any) {
  return row['key'];
}
```

I would like to be able to declare a template in my parent component to modify the data in the child component. An example of this would be to convert the quiz score to a percent or to format the date without directly changing the data in the component. I envision something similar to the following:

```
<ng-template #quizScore>
  {{ someReferenceToData | percent }} // This treatment gets passed to child
</ng-template>
```

And by passing this into my child component, it would take my rendered data and format it using the percent pipe. I've done some research on `ngTemplateOutlet`, `ngComponentOutlet`, `ng-content`, etc. but am unsure of the best approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to pass `TemplateRef`s from your parent component to your child (table) component. Going based on your current approach, one way to do that would be to create another array for `@ViewChild` references in the parent component, and pass it to the table component.

However, I would suggest a little refactoring by creating an interface for your column configuration, that has `header`,`key`, and optionally a `customCellTemplate`. Something like:

### **Refactor**

```
import { TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

export interface TableColumnConfig {
  header: string;
  key: string;
  customCellTemplate?: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Then you could simplify the inputs of your child component

```
// CHILD COMPONENT
@Input() columnConfigs: TableColumnConfig[];
@Input() rows: any[];
```

### **In Parent Component**

Your vision for the custom cell template definition in the parent is on the right track, you'll need to access the data though.

HTML

```
<app-table
  [columnConfigs]="columnConfigs"
  [rows]="rows">
</app-table>

<!-- name the $implicit variable 'let-whateverIwant', see below for where we set $implicit -->
<!-- double check variable spelling with what you are trying to interpolate -->
<ng-template #quizScore let-someReferenceToData>
  {{ someReferenceToData | percent }} // The parent component can do what it likes to the data and even styles of this cell.
</ng-template>
```

TS - template references are undefined until `ngOnInit` / `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hooks

```
// PARENT COMPONENT
@ViewChild('quizScore', { static: true }) customQuizTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

public columnConfigs: TableColumnConfiguration[];
public rows: Quiz[] = [
  { 'John', 'Doe', 0.75, '2020-01-03T18:18:34.549Z' },
  { 'Jane', 'Doe', 0.85, '2020-01-03T18:19:14.893Z' }
];

ngOnInit() {
  this.columnConfigs = [
    {key: 'firstName', header: 'First'},
    {key: 'lastName', header: 'Last'},
    {key: 'quizScore', header: 'Score', customCellTemplate: customQuizTemplate},
    {key: 'quizDate', header: 'Date'}
  ]
}
```

**Note about `static:true` vs `static:false`** - the template ref is static unless it's dynamically rendered with something like `*ngIf` or `*ngFor`. `static:true` will initialize the template ref in `ngOnInit`, `static:false` will initialize it in `ngAfterViewInit`.

### **In Child Component**

You've already got the nested *ngFor in place in the table, but youll need to do some content projection if there is a customCellTemplate.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td *ngFor="let col of columnConfigs">
    <!-- if there is no customCellTemplate, just render the data -->
    <div *ngIf="!col.customCellTemplate; else customCellTemplate">
        {{ render(col.key, row) }}
    </div>

    <ng-template #customCellTemplate>
      <!-- expose data, you could expose entire row if you wanted. but for now this only exposes the cell data -->
      <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="col.customCellTemplate"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: {{ render(col.key, row) }} }">
      </ng-template>
    </ng-template>  
  </td>
</tr>
```

Sidenote: I would replace `render(col.key, row)` with `row[col.key]` if you can.

Comment: This works perfectly except for when I use a pipe on the data in the template that gets passed into the child component. When I do `{{ someReferenceToData | percent }}` nothing is rendered, but there are no errors in the console. I can step through the debugger and see if I can figure out what is happening from here, but thought I would mention it.

Comment: Not sure if you're using the `render()` function, but it may be something to do with that? Can't say for certain. I tend to avoid functions in the template where I can. I havent had problems using `row[col.key]`.

Comment: It's definitely not the render function as that has been removed. I'll post a follow up comment once I get it figured out in case others run into the same issue.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to get this working by changing the template I was passing into the child component to `<ng-template #customCellTemplate *ngTemplateOutlet="col.customCellTemplate; context: { $implicit: render(col.key, row) }"></ng-template>`

Comment: sorry to add another comment an entire year later, a recent notification led me to re-reading my answer and I found a small typo in a snippet, where I had let-someReferenceData (missing 'To') in the template but someReferenceToData in the interpolation. Updated snippet to let-someReferenceToData. This may explain the issue you saw.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create an event listener in the child component and render the correct data when emitting the formatted data using RxJS.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here would be to define a `column` object like this:

```js
export class Column {
  header: string;
  key: string;
  type: ColumnType; // An enumerator: plain text, number, percentage, date
}
```

And in your child component you have maybe pipes or other functions that handle the display logic for the different types of columns

```js
render(type: ColumnType, row: any) {
  switch(type) {
    case ColumnType.Date: 
      // format as date
      break;  
    case ColumnType.Number: 
      // Format number to 2 decimals for example
      break;  
  }
}
```

Comment: We tried this in a prior iteration of the component. It definitely works, but we ended up with a giant switch statement to handle one-offs because `date` would sometimes be `shortDate` and other times it would be `longDate` etc. This time around we are looking for greater flexibility.